# I can't figure out why command prompt is skipping inputs to a simple C++ program in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Here's the program I'm having trouble with, or maybe something is configured wrong in Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    //define variables
    int name;
    int income;
    float tax;

    //Get the users name
    cou << "Please enter your full name \n";
    cin >> name;

    //Get the users income
    cout << "Please enter your annual income: \n";
    cin >> income;

    //tax conditions
    if (income < 50000)
    {
        cout << name; cout << "'s tax rate is 33% and the total income and amount taxed is: \n";
        tax = income * 0.33; 

        cout << income; cout << "dollars \n";
            cout << tax; cout << "dollars \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << name; cout << "'s tax rate is 38% and the total income and amount taxed is: \n";
        tax = income * 0.38;

        cout << income; cout << "dollars \n";
        cout << tax; cout << "dollars \n";
    }
system("pause");

    return 0;




}
```

It's supposed to calculate the tax on the users income. It does this fine, but as soon as I add the second cin >> name input at the top the command prompt accepts it as an input, then skips the second input and outputs a bunch of random numbers and characters.

This is the output in the command prompt:

```
Please enter your full name:
Bob Steve
Please enter your annual income:
-858993460's tax rate is 33% and the total income and amount taxed is:
-858993460dollars
-2.83468e+08dollars
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As soon as the first input "Bob Steve" is entered the rest automatically displays. I appreciate any help offered on this problem.

Comment: Your `name` should be of type `std::string`, not `int`. It should be accepted from the standard input via the `std::getline` function.

Comment: Always test IO transactions to make sure they succeeded. eg: `if (cin >> name) { /*use name*/ } else { /* name is bogus. clean up and try again*/ }`

Comment: Input with the `>>` operator separates on *space*. If you learned how to step through your code with a debugger it would be detected very easily, or if you [learned how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) in general.

Comment: Formatted input skips whitespace by default. It reads Bob, then tries to read Steve into a number and fails and all other input also fails because the stream is in an error state. Check to make sure your input succeeds.

Comment: Hello. My name is 4, and I make -37 dollars a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you are trying to input a word with a space in it.
For example if you input "Bar Foo" as an input for the name then the next input will be skipped. Try breaking the name into two different variables like " string firstname; string lastname;".
Anyways, I also see that there are some syntax errors in your code, the name data-type should be at least a character array or an std::string to store the persons name.

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
```

You can also use std::getline() to handle multi-spaced inputs as well.

Comment: [`std::getline` is also useful when reading names.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) `firstName` `lastName` can't handle Cher or Victor Von Doom.

Comment: Wow thankyou so much for the reply, totally clears my mistakes up! It's for an online C++ class i'm taking and I posted my problem on our discussion board, but no one replied so I headed over here. So, this is my first post and I also apologize for posting a duplicate, I did look around for awhile, but nothing familiar came up so I apologize. Again, thanks for the help!